react-native-contacts search with number or email
with react-native-contacts
with a minimum of code, how to do a getContactsMatchingString search with a phone number or an email?
with android it works well but only on IOS, it always returns empty.
I would like to do personalized searches such that you only enter the first two or more digits of the number or the beginning of an email
Certainly, we have two methods which are:

getContactsByPhoneNumber
getContactsByEmailAddress
but the problem with these two methods is that they are precise searches (the number or email must be complete and consistent with what we have in our directory)

      const contacts = await Contacts.getContactsMatchingString(query);
      console.log(" ~ getContactsMatchingString ~ contacts:", contacts);


getContactsByPhoneNumber not OK
getContactsByEmailAddress. not OK
getContactsMatchingString only with android it works, on the other hand if you do a search by name or first name it's perfect

